# SVG using textPath a symbol not rendering in Firefox

Tags: css, svg

Using a textPath within a symbol doesn't render in Firefox.  It renders fine in the latest Chrome and IE, but when I try to reference a symbol, the svg text doesn't render in Firefox (37.0.1) - first box appears empty.  With the code below (no external dependencies), there should be two boxes with the word `Test` flowing vertically in the centre of each.

**EDIT:**  I originally thought this issue somehow involved the Flexbox layout, until [Paul](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1292848/paul-lebeau) pointed out that the issue exists even without the flexbox layout.

The html is:

```
<div>
    <svg id="not_working" viewBox="0 0 250 1200" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
        <symbol id="test_symbol1" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" viewBox="0 0 250 1200">
            <path id="test_symbol_path" d="M 100 1200 L 100 0" />
            <text font-size="100" fill="red">
                <textPath text-anchor="middle" startoffset="50%" xlink:href="#test_symbol_path">Test</textPath>
            </text>
        </symbol>
        <use xlink:href="#test_symbol1" />
    </svg>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 250 1200" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
        <path id="test_text" d="M 100 1200 L 100 0" />
        <text font-size="100" fill="green">
            <textPath text-anchor="middle" startoffset="50%" xlink:href="#test_text">Test</textPath>
        </text>
    </svg>
</div>
```

And the css is:

```
div {
    height:200px;
    width: 200px;
    display: flex;
    flex:1;
    flex-direction: row;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
svg {
    border: 1px solid black;
    flex-grow: 0;
    flex-shrink: 1;
    flex-basis: 50%;
}
```

JS Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/x7ydw2df/6/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it has anything to do with flexbox.  The `<textPath>` element doesn't render even if you don't use flexbox.

See: https://jsfiddle.net/x7ydw2df/7/

It seems to be related to the textPath being in a symbol.  Please report your discovery as a bug at Mozilla.

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Core&component=SVG

Comment: Thanks.  I've submitted a [bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1154729) with them.

Comment: I fixed that some time ago. Roll on Firefox 38.

Comment: Thanks @Robert.  I went as far as resetting my profile to see if bug was still present, but didn't install nightly build (until you closed my bug as a duplicate).  I can confirm it is fixed in the nightly (Yay).